# Classic 'inner div to fill rest of height'-question!

Tags: html, css

I've tried to find a solution that matches my basic CSS problems when designed new pages.
But without luck, even though it has come close...

Say I have the following:

- A main div wrapper to fill 100% height (no problem)
- An inner div to fill rest of height **PLUS** the extra contents (scrollable) <-- this is hard IMO.
  [image]

The `Content` div should fill the rest of the height...

*The only problem* is that if I use `position:absolute`,`left:0;bottom:0;top:0;` on the `Content`; if the contents of the `Content` exceeds the browser's initial height, this will happen:

[image]

... And the page will be weird-looking. **Would be nice, if the Div itself, would scale WITH the contents... :-)**

How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is really no good way to do this in CSS (although maybe a guru will come by and show me wrong), may be helpful to read about sticky footers,

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

also discussed on several threads here, if you are trying to ensure that the footer won't appear halfway down the page. This can be accomplished purely with CSS, and if you absolutely need the content div to take up the remaining space (nothing a body background shouldn't be able to take care of..), then you can use javascript to set the height of the element to be document.height - the height of the header and footer.

I'm sorry I wasn't able to give a better response, 3 minutes left on my laptop battery, but I'll be back.

Comment: My outer div does already have `overflow:hidden;` applied to it... Want to see some code?

Comment: gimme 1 sec, testing it out, probably won't need to see more, you gave a good description :)

Comment: This is basically what I've been trying: http://jsfiddle.net/YBtbt/1/ PS. It's not supposed to scroll in the `Content` DIV - but the whole page...

Comment: @Your edit - Applying `overflow:auto;` results just like my 2nd picture in my question. And the contents flows out of the `Content` div

Comment: looking for a way to do it with the absolute, but do you need it positioned absolutely?

Comment: Not at all! :) This is merely a draft to improve my CSS-skills. Used absolute as a position since it's how I know it

Comment: Ok, in that case I'm going to completely rework my answer to better explain, so that I can be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help out - much appreciated

Comment: No problem, although I'm not sure you'll be happy with the answer, there really isn't a sane way to do this with CSS

Comment: It's alright. Thanks for the link. I'll check it out and try out more options